# How to concatenate Object to specific object in Array of Objects in useState React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

I am new to `reactjs`. I have used `state` in `react hooks`. I have declared a `state` which is shown below

```
const [data1, setData1] = useState([{"orderID":"o1"},{"orderID":"o2"}])
```

I have declared a `orderID` with number `o2`

```
var orderID = "o2"
```

I have another `state` data

```
const [data2, setData2] = useState({"Waist":"3", "Hip":"2"})
```

I want to update the `data2` object to `data1` array of objects which has the `OrderID` of `o2`

**Required Output:**

```
console.log(data1)

[{"orderID":"o1"},{"orderID":"o2", "Waist":"3", "Hip":"2"}]
```

I want to set the `Object` to `data1` state. I don't know how to make it. I have searched Stack Overflow. But I can't find Solutions. Please Help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach.

```js
setData1(prevData1 => 
    prevData1.map(element => element.orderID === orderId ? ({
        ...element,
        ...data2
    }) : element))
```